# Is the running maximum of random walk a martingale?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales, random-walk

> I need to determine wheather the process of running maximum of random walk is a martingale or not. We have random variables $\xi_i : \forall i \rightarrow P(\xi_i = 1) = P(\xi_i = - 1) = \frac{1}{2}$ also we have a random walking $S_n = \sum_{k = 1}^n \xi_i, S_0 = 0$. Denote $M_n = \max(\xi_1, ..., \xi_n)$. Is the process $M_n$ a martingale adapted to the filtration $\sigma\{\xi_1, ..., \xi_n\}$?

I tried to check a martingale property, that $\forall \ m \le n \rightarrow E(M_n \mid \sigma\{\xi_1, ..., \xi_m\}) = M_m$. As I understood, in case $\max(\xi_1, .., \xi_n) = \max(\xi_{m+1}, .., \xi_n)$ the conditional expected value $$E(\max(\xi_{m+1},...,\xi_n) \mid \sigma\{\xi_1,...,\xi_n\}) = E(\max(\xi_{m+1},...,\xi_n)) \neq M_m \rightarrow M_n$$ isn't a martingale. I understand that it's not a full solution, but some intuitive considerations. Could you please tell me whether the direction of thinking is right or not. And would be grateful for any hints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(M_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is not a martingale since it doesn't have constant expectation. *Indeed:* Clearly, we have

$$\mathbb{E}(M_1) = \mathbb{E}(\xi_1)=0.$$

On the other hand,

$$\mathbb{P}(M_2 = -1) = \mathbb{P}(\xi_1=-1,\xi_2=-1) = \frac{1}{4}$$

and so

$$\mathbb{P}(M_2 = 1) = \frac{3}{4}$$

implying

$$\mathbb{E}(M_2) = (-1) \frac{1}{4} + \frac{3}{4} = \frac{1}{2} \neq 0 = \mathbb{E}(M_1).$$

Comment: I'm sorry, I revealed that I didn't type my question properly, it should be $max(S_1,..S_n)$ not $max(\xi_1,...,\xi_n)$ and for such process expected value seems equal to zero. Do you know, the way I should follow to solve this task, or it would be better to edit the question?

Comment: @DF Why do you think that $\mathbb{E}(\max\{S_1,S_2\})=0$?(... and the proper way would be to ask a new question... You should avoid changing the question after it has been answered.)

Comment: yes, I'm wrong, it's equal to $\frac{1}{2}$ and $M_n$ isn't a martingale. Thank you again :)